# gdb print double pointer

Tags: c, gdb

I have a `struct` as

```
typedef struct p {
    struct m **k;
    // ..other member
} p_t;

p_t *pi;
```

I need to access the value `pi->k[1]` through gdb.

Comment: Well, for accessing `pi->k[1]`, have you tried `pi->k[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

`(gdb) print pi->k[1]`